# Can templates coexist and still one of them be used in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, slim-lang

I am semi-forking Redmine for my company and rarely pulling improvements from upstream. I prefer to use SLIM over ERB for views. My idea is that I want to keep erb files intact for the sake of easier diff-ing when I pull changes from upstream, still I want to only use SLIM versions of the templates.
So where I have

```
index.html.erb
```

and

```
index.html.slim
```

I want Rails to only search for index.html.slim and take no notice about the existence of the erb variant. Is it possible to make the two variants coexist side-by-side in the same folder and only use SLIM here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in the controllers:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render handlers: [:slim] }
end
```

Or if you want to override it specifically for one view:

```
render "path/view", handlers: [:slim]
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me this! It let me explore 'handlers' and combined your methods with this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981379/97300 and it just fits.

Comment: This works for a clean Rails project but Redmine must have some tricky overrides and won't find slim templates next to erb ones.